# get page that give 'echo json_encode' by curl return error

Tags: php, json, curl

I tried get page by curl like this

```
        $headers = array(
            "Content-Type: application/json",
        );
        $myCurl = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($myCurl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "php");
        curl_setopt($myCurl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($myCurl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

        $options = array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,   
        );
        curl_setopt_array( $myCurl, $options );
        $response = curl_exec($myCurl);
        $httpCode = curl_getinfo($myCurl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

        if(curl_errno($myCurl)){
            $handle = fopen('myCurlError.txt', 'a+'); 
            fwrite($handle, print_r(curl_error($myCurl), true) . "\n");
            fclose($handle);
        }

        if(!curl_errno($myCurl)){
            curl_close($myCurl);
            $ret = json_decode($response, true);
        } else {
            curl_close($myCurl);
        }
```

page that I tried to get by curl return result of function that end like this

```
echo json_encode($result);
```

that must return this
`{"success":true,"redirect":"https:myurl"}`

in log of function it show result but curl dont get this result and return errors:
504 or 500 or this Operation timed out after 2001 milliseconds with 0 out of -1 bytes received

Comment: What's the value of $url variable?

Comment: You should probably show the code of the page that you're requesting

Comment: I forgot to say that if I get this page by jquery ajax work fine but if i get by curl its get errors

Comment: I cant show url but I can show header of page

Comment: Maybe I must use user_agent header and cookie ?

Comment: if you are expecting json, you dont need to `json_encode` it, you already got what you asked for.  Which is correct : the title, the code, or your comment ?

Comment: its all correct